# "Dis-" prefix meaning and etymology

Tags: etymology, prefixes, negative-prefixes

Most native speakers are used to "dis-" as a prefix having a negative or opposite connotation (disengaged, dissatisfied, disinterested). However, in rare cases, "dis-" is actually an amplifying prefix, most notably in "disgruntled" and "disheveled".

Do these distinct families of "dis-" prefixed words have some common root? What's the reason for the two nearly opposite meanings?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that "dis" is an amplifying prefix in those two words? The OED certainly doesn't confirm this.

Comment: http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/06/gruntled.html I was hoping for some more sources on the origin of the prefix usage in that manner. There is also a Grammar Girl blog about the back-formation of "gruntled" as an accepted word, among others: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dont-worry-be-gruntled

Comment: If you look at the etymology for [dishevel](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dishevel&allowed_in_frame=0) you find that "dis" is not an intensifier, but rather means "apart".

Comment: *What's the reason for the two nearly opposite meanings?*  About 2500 years of absorbing words from at least a dozen different languages.

Comment: But you get a *discount* when the *disinterested* clerk gets *disengaged* and fails to ***count*** your purchases correctly.  Note that *disinterested* and *uninterested* are different words with different meanings, and, while [the Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tracted) defines *tracted* to mean *focused*, I consider this to be a case of reverse etymology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant meaning of "dis-" in the OED is:

> "With verbs having already a sense of division, solution, separation,
>   or undoing, the addition of dis- was naturally intensive, ‘away, out
>   and out, utterly, exceedingly’, as in disperīre to perish utterly,
>   dispudēre to be utterly ashamed, distædēre to be utterly wearied or
>   disgusted; hence it became an intensive in some other verbs, as
>   dīlaudāre to praise exceedingly, discupĕre to desire vehemently,
>   dissuavīrī to kiss ardently. In the same way, English has several
>   verbs in which dis- adds intensity to words having already a sense of
>   undoing, as in disalter, disaltern, disannul."